# Renewed Push Notification certificate not working on some devices

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, devicetoken

Last year i created a push notification certificate and PEM for my app. 
In my app, when a user logs in, the device token will be send to server. By default, the apps remains logged in until user logout from the app. Now the push certification expired and i created a new one and generated a new pem file. But when i try to send a push notification to all devices. It fails, but i got a message as "Connected successfully".

I have around 100 users in my app. Old users are not getting any notification. But if i delete my app and re-download. It works. But i don't want the user to delete and install the app again. I have all user's device token in my server . But none of them is working.

I come across this answer. Will it make any difference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825777/711963

Note: My app support versions from iOS V5.1.1

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the new certificate has the same application ID as the old one? Replacing the push certificate for the same application ID doesn't require any changes in the apps already installed.

Comment: Yes. i downloaded the old app from app store and logged in again. It works. But the user already logged in couldn't get the notification.

Comment: Are you sure your DB contains the device token of that already logged in user? Perhaps you are not even sending a notification to that user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create new provisioning profile and creating the PEM file from that ?

Also create the new IPA from new created profile and add all the device token into it .

Comment: No. I didn't create PEM from Provisioning Profile. I just created from certificate and p12 file. Do i really need to create a new profile? Is it necessary to create new IPA? Apple has mentioned that no need to create new build.